# Quickest Algorithmn for Normalization of Region Proposals

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, normalization

In order to normalize the region proposal algorithm (that is, applying regression to every X-by-Y area of an image), I need to create a region proposal normalization when summing the activation of each proposal. Currently, for a 128x128 patch of an image, in Python I'm running this bit of code

```
region_normalization = np.zeros(image.shape)
for x in range(0,image.shape[0]-128):
    for y in range(0,image.shape[0]-128):
        region_normalization[x:x+128,y:y+128] = 
        np.add(region_normalization[x:x+128,y:y+128],1)`
```

but this is particularly inefficient. What would be a quicker and/or more pythonic implementation of this algorithm?

Thanks!

Comment: You need these to be overlapping windows, rather than tiling the original figure?  Also, is this for some sort of convolution operation (CNN)?

Comment: Yup, these need to be overlapping windows for robustness. This is for regional binary classification of images (for segmentation).

Comment: Great.  Have you considered using some convolutional neural network for this design?  Depending on what you do with the output, you might be able to utterly bypass this level of programming and let the framework (Torch, Theano, Caffe, CNTK, TensorFlow, etc) do the matrix optimization for you.

Comment: @Prune Yes, I'm aware that using a CNN would be the state-of-the-art (as well as the quicker) solution, but this is for a community unfamiliar with the state of machine learning. I'm doing a review of classical CV/ML methodologies as well as the state-of-the-art.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reverse engineer it!**

Well, let's take a look at the output for a small image  and smaller `N` case, as we will try to reverse engineer this loopy code. So, with `N = 4`  (where `N` was `128` in the original case) and image.shape = `(10,10)`, we would have :

```
In [106]: region_normalization
Out[106]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  4,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8,  8,  8,  6,  4,  2,  0],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12, 12, 12,  9,  6,  3,  0],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16, 16, 16, 12,  8,  4,  0],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16, 16, 16, 12,  8,  4,  0],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16, 16, 16, 12,  8,  4,  0],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12, 12, 12,  9,  6,  3,  0],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8,  8,  8,  6,  4,  2,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  4,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

We do see a symmetry there and this symmetry happens to be across both `X` and `Y` axes. One more thing that jumps out at us is that each element is product of its starting row and column element. So, the idea would be to get the first row and first column and perform element-wise multiplication among their elements. Since the first row and first column are identical, we just need to get that once and use it with additional axis and let [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) handle those multiplications. Thus, the implementation would be -

```
N = 128
a1D = np.hstack((np.arange(N)+1,np.full(image.shape[0]-2*N-1,N,dtype=int),\
                                                          np.arange(N,-1,-1)))

out = a1D[:,None]*a1D
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [137]: def original_app(image):
     ...:     region_normalization = np.zeros(image.shape,dtype=int)
     ...:     for x in range(0,image.shape[0]-128):
     ...:         for y in range(0,image.shape[0]-128):
     ...:             region_normalization[x:x+128,y:y+128] = \
     ...:             np.add(region_normalization[x:x+128,y:y+128],1)
     ...:     return region_normalization
     ...: 
     ...: def vectorized_app(image):        
     ...:     N = 128
     ...:     a1D = np.hstack((np.arange(N)+1,np.full(image.shape[0]-2*N-1,N,\
     ...:                                        dtype=int),np.arange(N,-1,-1)))
     ...: 
     ...:     return a1D[:,None]*a1D
     ...: 

In [138]: # Input
     ...: image = np.random.randint(0,255,(512,512))

In [139]: np.allclose(original_app(image),vectorized_app(image)) #Verify
Out[139]: True

In [140]: %timeit original_app(image)
1 loops, best of 3: 13 s per loop

In [141]: %timeit vectorized_app(image)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.4 ms per loop
```

Super speedup there!

Comment: Figured this out, but had a much worse implementation (was using some for loops to do this). Thanks for the nice pythonic answer with a good explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The value of any given point i,j in your renormalization is equal to the number of 128x128 windows that contain it. Note that this is the product of the degrees of freedom on the x axis and on the y axis. So all we have to do is figure out the degrees of freedom for each possible x and y, value, then use broadcasting or np.outer to get the result.

```
import numpy as np
image = np.zeros((200,200))

window=128
region_normalization = np.zeros(image.shape)
for x in range(0,image.shape[0]-window):
    for y in range(0,image.shape[0]-window):
        region_normalization[x:x+window,y:y+window] = np.add(region_normalization[x:x+window,y:y+window],1)

def sliding(n, window=128):
    arr = np.zeros(n)
    for i in xrange(n):
        #want to find all s such that 0<=s<=i<s+128<n
        #thus, s < min(i+1, n-128), s >= max(0, i-window+1) 
        arr[i] = min(i+1, n-window) - max(0,i-window+1)
    return arr


def normalizer(image, window = 128):
    m,n = image.shape   
    res = np.zeros(shape)
    if m < window or n < window: return res
    x_sliding = sliding(m, window)
    y_sliding = sliding(n, window)
    print x_sliding
    res = np.outer(x_sliding,y_sliding)
    return res

print np.allclose(normalizer(image, window=128),region_normalization)
```